# Variables after the colon in a constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, ctor-initializer

I am still learning C++ and trying to understand it. I was looking through some code and saw:

```
point3(float X, float Y, float Z) :
x(X), y(Y), z(Z)  // <----- what is this used for
{
}
```

What is the meaning of the "x(X), y(Y), z(Z)" sitting beside the constructor's parameters?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272680/c-constructor-syntax-question-noob. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632484/c-initialization-question

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's a way of invoking the constructors of members of the point3 class. if x,y, and z are floats, then this is just a more efficient way of writing this

```
point3( float X, float Y, float Z):
{
   x = X;
   y = Y;
   z = Z;
}
```

But if x, y & z are classes, then this is the only way to pass parameters into their constructors

Comment: To clarify: If the members are non-PoD types, the members won't be default-constructed and a copy-constructor won't need to be invoked on those members if you use an initialization list. Therefore, it's more efficient.

Comment: **`PoD` = "plain old data"

Answer (score 5):

In your example `point3` is the *[constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s16xw1a8.aspx)* of the class with the same name (`point3`), and the stuff to the right of the colon `:` before the opening bracket `{` is the [initialization list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301399.aspx), which in turn constructs (i.e. initializes) `point3`'s member variables (and can also be used to pass arguments to constructors in the base class[es], if any.)

Answer (score 0):

Member initialization as others have pointed out. 
But it is more important to know the following:

When the arguments are of the type float or other built-in types, there's no clear advantages except that using member initialization rather than assignment (in the body of the constructor) is more idiomatic in C++.

The clear advantage is if the arguments are of user-defined classes, this member initialization would result in calls to copy constructors as opposed to default constructors if done using assignments (in the constructor's body).