# How to initialize a object in the constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, lint

I have the following code in C++:

// This is the header file, test.h

```
typedef struct
{
   int a;
   int b;
} Numbers;

class Test
{
private;
   Numbers numbers_;
};
```

//This is the source file, test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

Test::Test()
{}
```

Then I run lint on it, it says Warning 1401 member "numbers_" not initialized by constructor

I know how to initialize build in types in constructor, but how to initialize type like `Numbers`?

Comment: Define a constructor for your struct `Numbers`, else using a initialization list in class `Test` doesn't help much. And then use the `Numbers` constructor in the initialization list of `Test`

Comment: `typedef struct` – No. This makes absolutely no sense in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to write a custom constructor for the Numbers class you can also simply initialize the fields of the member object in your Test constructor:

```
Test::Test()
{
    numbers_.a = 0;
    numbers_.b = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you should do:

```
typedef struct numbers
{
   int a;
   int b;
   numbers()
   {
       a = 0;
       b = 0;
   }
} Numbers;

class Test
{
private:
   Numbers numbers_;
public:
    Test() : numbers_()
    {
    }
};
```

Note that:

1. I named the `struct` as `numbers`, and then gave it a *parameterless constructor*.
2. Also, there was a compile-time error in your code. The *[access specifers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447498/what-are-access-specifiers-should-i-inherit-with-private-protected-or-public)* (`private` in your case) must be followed by a *colon*(`:`), not a *semi-colon*(`;`)
3. I added a *parameterless constructor* for `Test`, and used *initializer_list* to call the constructor of `Numbers`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a constructor for your struct.

You'll find some example here:

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145822/struct-constructor-sytax)

Comment: It's always best to provide an answer and an explanation than just providing a link ( links might get changed ).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to initialise class members.

You could aggregate-initialise it, giving values to each member:

```
Test::Test() : numbers_{42,53} {}
```

or you could value-initialise it, setting each member to zero:

```
Test::Test() : numbers_() {}
```

Alternatively, if you don't particularly need the `Numbers` class to be plain data, then you could let it initialise itself. You could give each member an in-class initialiser:

```
int a = 42;
int b = 53;
```

or you could give it a constructor:

```
struct Numbers  // the class needs a name to declare a constructor
{
    Numbers() : a(42), b(53) {}
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

Or, perhaps, you could ignore or disable the warning, but be careful to assign values to the uninitialised members before using them.