# C++, What does the colon after a constructor mean?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Variables After the Colon in a Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349978/variables-after-the-colon-in-a-constructor)
>   [C++ constructor syntax question (noob)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272680/c-constructor-syntax-question-noob)

I have some C++ code here:

```
class demo 
{
private:
    unsigned char len, *dat;

public:
    demo(unsigned char le = 5, unsigned char default) : len(le) 
    { 
        dat = new char[len];                                      
        for (int i = 0; i <= le; i++)                             
            dat[i] = default;
    }

    void ~demo(void) 
    {                                            
        delete [] *dat;                                           
    }
};

class newdemo : public demo 
{
private:
    int *dat1;

public:
    newdemo(void) : demo(0, 0)
    {
     *dat1 = 0;                                                   
     return 0;                                                    
    }
};
```

My question is, what are the `: len(le)` and `: demo(0, 0)` called?

Is it something to do with inheritance?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272680/c-constructor-syntax-question-noob, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349978/variables-after-the-colon-in-a-constructor, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445330/importance-of-a-singlecolon-in-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632484/c-initialization-question

Comment: **DO NOT DELETE** questions with good answers! [Jeff said so!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50069/why-are-we-deleting-instead-of-merging/50106#50106)

Comment: @KonradRudolph One of these duplicate questions was deleted, unfortunately: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445330/importance-of-a-singlecolon-in-c

Comment: @Anderson Ah what a shame. I cast an undelete vote – but it needs three. :-(

Comment: @KonradRudolph Just FYI, [Jeff's merged question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434/how-to-improve-problem-solving-skills) in that meta post was also deleted, so the community might have moved on since then.

Answer (score 441, accepted):

As others have said, it's a member initializer list. You can use it for two things:

1. Calling base class constructors
2. Initializing data members before the body of the constructor executes

For case #1, I assume you understand inheritance (if that's not the case, let me know in the comments). So you are simply calling the constructor of your base class.

For case #2, the question may be asked: "Why not just initialize it in the body of the constructor?" The importance of the member initializer lists is particularly evident for `const` members. For instance, take a look at this situation, where I want to initialize `m_val` based on the constructor parameter:

```
class Demo
{
    Demo(int& val) 
     {
         m_val = val;
     }
private:
    const int& m_val;
};
```

By the C++ specification, this is illegal. We cannot change the value of a `const` variable in the constructor, because it is marked as const. So you can use the initializer list:

```
class Demo
{
    Demo(int& val) : m_val(val)
     {
     }
private:
    const int& m_val;
};
```

That is the only time that you can change a `const` data member. And as Michael noted in the comments section, it is also the only way to initialize a reference that is a data member.

Outside of using it to initialize `const` data members, it seems to have been generally accepted as "the way" of initializing members, so it's clear to other programmers reading your code.

Comment: To be clear - in addition to initializing `const` members, it's the only way to initialize reference members, whether `const` or not (since an assignment to a reference is an assignment to what the reference refers to).

Comment: can we do something like this
`Demo():m_val(NULL)`

I am doing this but its giving me errors, any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: @Smashery : Regarding `That is the only time that you can change a const member variable : `  something like `*const_cast<int*>(&m_val)+=5;` may be used to override constness & volatility

Comment: @Smashery **m_val = val;** in ctor is pointless even if **int& m_val** is not **const**. Your explanation would be clear if you'd not used references.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Burr extremely important comment

Comment: It would be useful to add the name of the feature number 2: the member initializer list.

Comment: @Smashery
that's not even more questionable than the confusing one : what'd be used in enclosure, bow or curly brace ?
As often seen e.g:
class Vector {
Vector(int s) :elem{new double[s]}, sz{s} { }
...
}

Comment: @MichaelBurr What's wrong with the constructor: `Demo(int &val) {m_val = val }` ? `val` can be passed to the constructor from outside to initialize a non-const `m_val`.

Comment: I thought this was the first question to pop in everyone's heads, but I don't see it mentioned in the comments. `You can use it for two things: Calling base class constructors`. Why would I want to call base class constructor if it is already implicitly called when instantiating a variable of child class type?

Answer (score 50):

This is called an initialization list.  It is for passing arguments to the constructor of a parent class.  Here is a good link explaining it: [Initialization Lists in C++](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html)

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It's called an initialization list.  It initializes members before the body of the constructor executes.

Answer (score 7):

It's called an initialization list. An initializer list is how you pass arguments to your member variables' constructors and for passing arguments to the parent class's constructor.

If you use `=` to assign in the constructor body, first the default constructor is called, then the assignment operator is called. This is a bit wasteful, and sometimes there's no equivalent assignment operator.

Comment: Following code shows that your comment about = is wrong.
Using initialization list, value will be set according to initialisation list.

Using assignment:
class cl {
public:
        cl() {
                cout<<"before setting is "<<va;
                va = 1;
                cout<<"after setting to 1 is "<<va;
        }

        int va;
};

before setting is -853905904
after setting to 1 is 1

Had the default constructor been called, va should have been 0 before the explicit assignment.

Answer (score 3):

It means that `len` is not set using the default constructor. while the `demo` class is being constructed.  For instance:

```
class Demo{
    int foo;
public:
    Demo(){ foo = 1;}
};
```

Would first place a value in foo before setting it to 1.  It's slightly faster and more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the constructor of its base class, demo.