# question about class

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why should I prefer to use member initialization list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list)
>   [C++ - what does the colon after a constructor mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785612/c-what-does-the-colon-after-a-constructor-mean)

here is following code

```
class vector2d {
public:
  double x,y;
  vector2d (double px,double py): x(px), y(py) {}
```

i dont understand this line

```
 vector2d (double px,double py): x(px), y(py) {}
```

is it same as
 `vector2d(double px,double py){   x=px;y=py;}?`  or?

Comment: cf. ["Should my constructors use "initialization lists" or "assignment"?"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6)

Comment: Duplicate of [Why should I prefer to use member initialization list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list)

Comment: And duplicate of [C++ - what does the colon after a constructor mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785612/c-what-does-the-colon-after-a-constructor-mean) which links to more duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's the same in your example. However, there's a subtle difference: x(px) initializes x to px, but x=px assigns it. You'll not know the difference for a `double`variable, but if x where a class there would be a big difference. Let's pretend that x is a class of type `foo`:

x(px) would call the foo copy constructor, foo::foo(foo &classToCopyFrom).

x=px on the other hand, would first call the `foo` default constructor, then it would call the `foo` assignment operator.

This is a good reason that you should prefer x(px) in most cases.