# derived clases in different files c++

Tags: c++, file, class, header, derived-class

How I do to make a main class in file_x.h, and file_x.cpp and then a derived class from the class made in file_x, in file_y.h and file_y.cpp

I have tried lots of things without any good results, Could you please give me an example with both classes with their constructor function, a variable, and a regular function in both classes?

I have this in window.h (main class header):

```
#ifndef WINDOW_H_
#define WINDOW_H_

#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_ttf.h"

#include "../../utils/event.h"
#include "../../utils/button.h"

using namespace std;

class bwindow{
    protected:
        SDL_Surface* up_bar;
        SDL_Surface* content;
        SDL_Surface* to_blit;
        SDL_Surface* text;

        vector <button*> botns;

        string name;
        int x;
        int y;

        bool pressed;
        int sx;
        int sy;
    public:
        bwindow(string,int,int,int,int,int*,int*);
        void graphic_update(SDL_Surface*);
        void logic_update(events*);
        ~bwindow();
        string get_name();
};
#endif /* WINDOW_H_ */
```

This in window.cpp (main class file):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_gfxPrimitives.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_ttf.h"

#include "../../utils/SDL_functions.h"
#include "../../utils/event.h"
#include "../../extra_data/extra_data.h"
#include "window.h"

using namespace std;

bwindow::bwindow(string title,int xp,int yp,int w,int h,int a[], int b[]){

    //seting variables
    x = xp;
    y = yp;
    sx = x;
    sy = y;
    name = title;
    pressed = false;


    //seting masks
    Uint32 rmask = 0x00000000;
    Uint32 gmask = 0x00000000;
    Uint32 bmask = 0x00000000;
    Uint32 amask = 0x00000000;

    //creating up_bar
    up_bar = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_SWSURFACE, w, 20, 32,rmask, gmask, bmask, amask);
    SDL_FillRect( up_bar, &up_bar->clip_rect, SDL_MapRGB( up_bar->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF ) );
    boxRGBA(up_bar   ,0, 0, w,20,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]);
    //creating content area
    content = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_SWSURFACE, w, h-30, 32,rmask, gmask, bmask, amask);
    boxRGBA(content,0, 0,w, h - 25,b[0],b[1],b[2], b[3]);
    //adding borders
    sdlf::add_border(up_bar,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,255);
    sdlf::add_border(content,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,255);

    //adding the up-text
    SDL_Color textColor = { 0 , 0 ,0  };

    TTF_Font *font;
    font =  fonts::load_john_han(15);

    text = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,title.c_str(),textColor);

    apply_surface(20,5,text,up_bar);

    //creating final surface
    to_blit = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_SWSURFACE, w, h, 32,rmask, gmask, bmask, amask);
}
void bwindow::graphic_update(SDL_Surface* screen){

    SDL_FillRect( to_blit, &to_blit->clip_rect, SDL_MapRGB( to_blit->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF ) );




    apply_surface(0,0, up_bar, to_blit);
    apply_surface(0,20,content,to_blit);

    apply_surface(x,y,to_blit,screen);

}
void bwindow::logic_update(events* evs){
    mouse m = evs->get_mouse();

    bool condition1 = m.x > x and m.x < x + up_bar->w;
    bool condition2 = m.y > y and m.y < y + up_bar->h;
    bool condition3 = m.left;
    if (condition1 and condition2){
        if (condition3 and pressed == false){
            pressed = true;
            sx = m.x - x;
            sy = m.y - y;
        }else if (not(condition3)){
            pressed = false;
        }
    }
    if (condition3 and pressed == true){
        x =   (m.x - sx) ;
        y =   (m.y - sy) ;
    }
}

string bwindow::get_name(){
    return name;
}

bwindow::~bwindow(){

}
```

this in window_types.h (derived class header):

```
#ifndef WINDOW_TYPES_H_
#define WINDOW_TYPES_H_

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "window.h"

using namespace std;

namespace windows{
    class message_window : public bwindow{
        private:
            vector <string> message;
            string title;
        public:
            message_window();
            void start(string,vector<string>,int);
            void test();
    };
}

#endif /* WINDOW_TYPES_H_ */
```

And this in window_types.cpp (Where I get an error "no matching function for call to ‘bwindow::bwindow()"):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "../../utils/utilsf.h"

#include "window_types.h"


using namespace std;
//HERE THE ERROR
windows::message_window::message_window(){

}
void windows::message_window::start(string title,vector <string> content,int s){
    int yp = 200;
    int xp = 300;
    int w = 100;
    int h = 50;
    int a[4];
    int b[4];

    a[0] = utilsf::randrange(0,256,s);
    a[1] = utilsf::randrange(0,256,s);
    a[2] = 200;
    a[3] = 255;

    b[0] = 200;
    b[1] = utilsf::randrange(0,256,s);
    b[2] = utilsf::randrange(0,256,s);
    b[3] = 255;

    bwindow(title,xp,yp,w,h,a,b);
}
void windows::message_window::test(){

}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what you have tried?

Comment: Can certainly be done, so you definitely need to show some code and explain in more detail on what problems you are seeing.

Comment: what have you tried? whats the problem ? compiling error linking error or what?

Comment: this error: "no matching function for call to ‘bwindow::bwindow()"

Comment: You need to include window.h inside your window_types.cpp.

Answer (score 0):

Your #includes are fine. However, you're not initializing your object instances correctly. You have to initialize the base class in the constructor of a derived class - and nowhere else! Moreover, you can't call the base constructor in the body of a derived constructor. C++ uses a special construct called an ['initialization list'](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/) to do that. It's denoted by a semicolon after the parameters and prior to the body of the constructor. See [What does a colon following a C++ constructor name do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785612/c-what-does-the-colon-after-a-constructor-mean) for more details.

Since you didn't initialize `bwindow` in the constructor of `message_window`, the C++ compiler inserted an implicit call to the default constructor, i.e. `bwindow::bwindow()`. But since no such constructor exists, you get a compiler error.

The `message_window` constructor should look something like this:

```
void windows::message_window::message_window(string title,
                                    vector <string> content,
                                    int s, int a[], int b[])
: bwindow(title, 300, 200, 100, 50, a, b),
  name(title),
  contents(content)
{
   // the constructor body is empty in this case
}
```

Note that you can't initialize the `a`and `b` arrays like you did before. The caller of `message_window` should probably have already done that.

Similarly the `bwindow` constructor [should use an initialization list](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/init-lists.html) this:

```
bwindow::bwindow(string title,int xp,int yp,int w,int h,int a[], int b[])
: x(xp), y(yp), sx(x), sy(y), name(title), pressed(false)
{
    //setting masks
    Uint32 rmask = 0x00000000;
    Uint32 gmask = 0x00000000;
    Uint32 bmask = 0x00000000;
    Uint32 amask = 0x00000000;

    //rest of the of the code omitted
}
```

Sidenote: You should [declare your destructors as virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors).