# Is there a difference between these 2 methods of initialising member variables?

Tags: c++, qt, initialization

```
Note::Note(Traymenu *trayMenuIn, QWidget *parent) :
    ui(new Ui::Note){
    ui->setupUi(this);

Note::Note(Traymenu *trayMenuIn, QWidget *parent){
    ui = new Ui::Note;
    ui->setupUi(this);
```

Both kinds are working. The above code is suggested by QtCreator, the lower code is what I would do if I had to write it on my own.

Note's private member is

```
Ui::Note *ui;
```

Comment: The former does initialization, the latter does assignment (of `ui`).

Comment: But isn't initialising the exact same thing as assigning a value to a declared pointer variable?

Comment: @user2366975 no. the former is at *construction* time, the latter undergoes default construction, *then* assignment.

Comment: Does it affect practical use in terms of stability, say deleting that object later on?

Comment: @user2366975: No, but it makes your code more robust. For example, you cannot accidentally access ui before it has the correct value.

Comment: Which one makes it more robuts? The QtCreator-one, no?

Comment: Yes, the one with the initialization list. But please read the FAQ entry in my answer for more details and some exceptions :)

Comment: @user2366975 The language's initializer list mantra should be utilized where at all possible. There are times, rarely, where it simply isn't feasible; this isn't one of them. And its a good habit to form.

Comment: And it's the only *possible* way for const or reference members.

Comment: "Does it affect practical use in terms of stability" Yes. Because you rely on an anti-idiom, and eventually you'll use it in presence of exceptions, and you'll [be sorry](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21971907/1329652).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the first form is initialization. The second form initializes `ui` with an undefined value, then *assigns* a value to it.

You should **prefer the first form** (initialization). See the related [C++ FAQ entry](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/init-lists.html).

Answer (score 2):

Although the difference is tiny, I would prefer the code snippet suggested by QtCreator: it uses the initialization syntax rather than the assignment syntax for the code that logically represents initialization.

Since the member being initialized is a pointer, there is no performance penalty even with the optimization turned off. However, it is a good idea to get into a habit of initializing as much as possible with the initialization list, because this prevents potential coding issues inside the constructor itself.