# Error: "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier" in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write some code that will make it easier for me to make SDL programs because I am learning and frequently start new projects. It basically needs to do all the standard SDL stuff. This is the code

```
namespace engine {

    class Engine
    {
    private:
        SDL_Renderer* renderer;
        SDL_Window* window;
        SDL_Event event;

        bool initialised = true;
        bool quit = false;

    public:

        Engine(const char* name, int x, int y, int w = SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, int h = SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, bool fullscreen = false)
        {
            window = SDL_CreateWindow(name, x, y, w, h, fullscreen);
            if (window == nullptr)
                initialised = false;
            renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
            if (renderer == nullptr)
                initialised = false;
        }

        ~Engine()
        {
            SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
            SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
        }

        void handleEvents()
        {
            while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
            {
                if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                {
                    quit = true;
                }
            }
        }

        virtual void update()
        {

        }

        virtual void render()
        {

        }

        void start()
        {
            if (initialised && !quit)
            {
                handleEvents();
                update();
                render();
            }
        }
    };

}
```

And then inherit from this to make a game class

```
class Game : public engine::Engine
{
private:
    engine::Engine game{"engine", 1200, 600};

public:

    game.update() override
    {

    }

    game.render() override
    {

    }
};
```

And something like this in main

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Game game();
    game.start();
    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting the error specified in the title in line `engine::Engine game{"engine", 1200, 600};` in `Game` class. I don't know if what I am doing is possible or how to do it. Thanks for any help

My Goal: I want some code, almost like a library that I can reuse with different SDL projects. This engine will be a separate library. So I want some kind of engine class that inherits from engine in my project. Say the class that inherits form engine is `game`. I want game to override update and render, so that I can call different drawing methods defined in engine from render function. That way I wont have to make window, renderer and handle for events every time I start a project. I don't know if this is a good way to do it but any better solutions are welcome.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I tried removing inheritance `class Game : public engine::Engine` to `class Game` but still get the same error

Comment: @ThomasSablik Is it `void game.update() override {}`. But then i cannot even use override is I am not using inheritance isn't it ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please describe your code.

Comment: Hang on. I will edit the question to explain

Comment: @ThomasSablik `A class can't contain an object of itself.` True, but: it's not doing that. `Game` is adding a member of its base type, not of the type itself. While weird and questionable, it's not illegal.

Comment: I'd have used parens instead of braces for `engine::Engine game{"engine", 1200, 600};`. Shrug.

Comment: *But then i cannot even use override is I am not using inheritance isn't it ?* ... then why does `Game` inherit from `engine::Engine`? Inheriting while also declaring a member of that type (compositing), makes little sense.

Comment: @3Dave So what should I do?

Comment: Thank @user4581301 for explaining it? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gutting `Engine` to make the example smaller. We don't need any of the SDL stuff in the class to show how to fix this up. Other than that, `Engine` looks pretty good. Don't need to change anything.

```cpp
namespace engine {

    class Engine
    {
    private:

        bool initialised = true;
        bool quit = false;

    public:

        Engine(const char* , int , int ) // simplified to remove the SDL stuff
        {
        }

        ~Engine() // may want this to be virtual. See link about virtual destructors
        {
        }

        void handleEvents()
        {
        }

        virtual void update()
        {

        }

        virtual void render()
        {

        }

        void start()
        {
            if (initialised && !quit)
            {
                handleEvents();
                update();
                render();
            }
        }
    };

}
```

Where things start going wrong is in trying to implement `Engine`. I'm going to comment inline as I make changes.

```cpp
class Game : public engine::Engine // correct
{
    // engine::Engine game{"engine", 1200, 600};
    // don't need an engine::Engine as a member. Game IS an Engine. 
public:
    Game (): 
        engine::Engine {"engine", 1200, 600} // initialize base class here
    {

    }
    // game.update() override
    void update() override // use a normal function definition
                           // Compiler will figure out the rest 
    {

    }

    // game.render() override
    void render() override // same as above
    {

    }
};
```

There's one small bug in `main`. The language has a little quirk where `TYPE name()` looks like a function, not a variable. This was cleaned up in C++11 with the addition of `{}` for more general initialization<sup>1</sup>.

```cpp
int main()
{
    // Game game(); declares a function, game, that returns a Game.
    Game game; // defines a variable named game that is a Game. Could also be Game game{};
               // note the different braces.
    game.start();
    return 0;
}
```

<sup>1</sup> Watch out when using this with container classes. `vector<int> test{5};` is a `vector` with one element containing five, NOT five elements containing the default zero you get from `vector<int> test(5);`.

Some additional reading:

[When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

[C++, What does the colon after a constructor mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785612/c-what-does-the-colon-after-a-constructor-mean)