# Nested Structures and using constructor for default value but conversion error

Tags: c++, constructor

For some reason when I set some default values for the nested structure with a constructor, I get the following error. But it seems the code should work. Can someone tell me where am I going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct smallDude
{
    int int1;
    int int2;

    // Default constructor
    smallDude()
    {
        int1 = 70;
        int2 = 60;
    }
};

struct bigDude 
{
    // structure within structure
    struct smallDude second;
}first;

int main() 
{
    bigDude first = {{2, 3}};
    cout<< first.second.int1<<endl;
    cout<< first.second.int2;
    return 0;
}
```

Error Output:

```
main.cpp:28:28: error: could not convert ‘{2, 3}’ from ‘’ to ‘smallDude’
   28 |     bigDude first = {{2, 3}};
      |                            ^
      |                            |
      |
```

Comment: In your declaration of `bigDude`, the `struct smallDude second;` member should be declared as just `smallDude second;` In any case, the error message shown does not match the code shown.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I edited the code, now, it should spit out the exact error (I must have copy pasted hastily in my trials). There was `bigDude first` instead of just `first` in the int main().

Comment: nope, the error still doesn't match the code. You can't initialize 2 data fields using 3 initializers. The code is using `{{2, 3}}` but the error message shows `{1, {3, 6}}`

Comment: @RemyLebeau my bad!!! Changed the error output now. `{1, {3, 6}}` was from a previous code that I was running. So sorry about this silly mistake twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`smallDude` has a user-declared default constructor, so it is not an aggregate type, and thus cannot be initialized from a `<brace-init-list>` like you are attempting to do.

There are two way you can fix that:

1. change the `smallDude` constructor to accept `int` inputs, like [@rturrado's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70042131/65863) shows:

```cpp
struct smallDude
{
    int int1;
    int int2;

    // constructor
    smallDude(int x, int y) : int1{x}, int2{y} {}
};
```

[Online Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c6enPTrPc)

2. get rid of all `smallDude` constructors completely (thus making `smallDude` an aggregate) and just assign default values to the members directly in their declarations, eg:

```cpp
struct smallDude
{
    int int1 = 70;
    int int2 = 60;
};
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/j9USuH)

Comment: The first method works but the second one isn't working on the online compiler that I am using. Is it a compiler issue? [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/1pW9dHh-z)

Comment: @AbdullaMasud add the `-std=c++14` flag to that compiler, and then it works fine.

Comment: Thank you! Though could you explain `: int1{x}, int2{y} {}` this part of the first method? or can you tell me what this is called so I can look it up?

Comment: @AbdullaMasud That's called _member initializer list_. It's the preferred option, rather than to initialize the members within the body of the constructor: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor.

Comment: @AbdullaMasud [C++, What does the colon after a constructor mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785612/)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `smallDude` constructor receiving two `int` values:

```cpp
smallDude(int x, int y) : int1{x}, int2{y} {}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/c6enPTrPc)