# Why does this overloaded operator<< work in an unexpected way?

Tags: c++

I wanted to create a method to add color to console output that would work in a similar way to `std::left` and `std::setw()`. I ended up with the code below, and it works exactly how I want it to. I understand how it works, but I would like some clarification on something.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

enum class color { blue = FOREGROUND_BLUE, green, cyan, red, purple, yellow, white, bright = FOREGROUND_INTENSITY };

class coutColor {
public:

    WORD Color;

    coutColor(color colorvalue) : Color((WORD)colorvalue) {  }
    ~coutColor() { SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, (WORD)7); }

};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const coutColor& colorout) {

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, colorout.Color);
    return os;

}

int main() {

    std::cout << coutColor(color::green) << "This text is green!\n";
    std::cout << color::red << "This text is red! " << 31 << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I understand how `coutColor(color::green)` works in the `cout` in `main()`, but why does just `color::red` by itself work as well?

I stumbled upon it by accident while testing different things.

How can it take the `enum` type `color` as an input, since it's not in the input parameters of the overloaded `operator<<`?

Why does it do the same thing as inputting `coutColor(color::red)`?

Comment: please one question per question. 2) no they are not the same. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor and here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor

Comment: You have an `operator<<` that takes an `ostream&` and `const coutColor&` as arguments. You have a constructor that converts a `color` to a `coutColor`. Overload resolution is capable of performing implicit conversions like this.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the link. I removed the side question. @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: Also notable that your `operator<<` is a bit misleading. If I understand the gist of `SetConsoleTextAttribute` and `GetStdHandle` correctly, then your `operator<<` isn't really making any changes to its argument `os` at all. That is, if you had some other stream `foo` and did `foo << coutColor(color::green)`, this would have the effect of making `std::cout`, not `foo`, have green text.

Comment: @NathanPierson: To be fair, OP did name his wrapper `coutColor`, so anyone thinking it operates on any stream other than `cout` is blind.  Now, it might not even work on `cout` if the standard output is redirected...

Comment: But then why write an `operator<<` that takes another stream at all?

Comment: @NathanPierson: You can't overload `operator<<` on the identity of its left operand.  In order to have it work with `cout` (and you do want to use `<<` because that ensures the correct ordering), you get it syntactically fitting other undesired streams as well.  (You also can't match `cout` specifically by type, e.g. `ostream_with_assign`, because chained `operator<<` loses the exact type)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> why does just `color::red` by itself work as well? ... How can it take the `enum` type `color` as an input, since it's not in the input parameters of the overloaded `operator<<`? Why does it do the same thing as inputting `coutColor(color::red)`?

It is because `coutColor`'s constructor is not marked as `explicit`.

When the compiler is looking for a suitable overload of `operator<<` for the expression `std::cout << color::red`, it finds your overload in scope and sees that:

1. `coutColor` is **implicitly** constructable from a `color` value
2. the operator takes a `coutColor` object by **const reference**

So, the compiler is able to create a **temporary** `coutColor` object, passing the `color` value to its constructor, and then pass that object to the operator.

> I have seen `function(input) : var(input) {}` before and I didn't know what it meant.

[C++, What does the colon after a constructor mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785612/)