# Trying to use abstract class members for a subtype

Tags: c++

I am doing a project for school that involves creating my own abstractions in C++.

I have an abstract class, called `Expression`:

```cpp
#pragma once
class Expression {
    virtual Expression *evaluate() = 0;
};
```

I have this so I can use other classes as expression subtypes. So, a `Number` could be an expression, and so could an `Add`, for example: `expression + expression`. And those can also be `Add` objects as well.

Unfortunately, I have encountered an issue. I don't know how to use members that are expressions, as expressions aren't objects:

```cpp
class Add : Expression{
    private:
        Expression left;
        Expression right;
    public:
        Add(Expression left, Expression right){
            this->left = left;
            this->right = right;
        }
};
```

The `left` and `right` members need to be as generic as possible, as they could be assigned a `Number` object, or any other expression subtype, including other `Add` objects. However, I can't have `Expression` members in my `Add` class without the compiler screaming at me.

Any advice?

```
Arithmetic.cpp:5:20: error: cannot declare field ‘Add::left’ to be of abstract type ‘Expression’
    5 |         Expression left;
      |                    ^~~~
```

Comment: The type `Expression` on its own is a _value_. An abstract class cannot be instantiated to produce a value. If you want to store arbitrary expressions, they must be pointers. Consider wrapping the stored expressions with `std::unique_ptr`. Review the chapter in your C++ learning material that introduces the concept of abstract classes.

Answer (score 1):

`Expression` is an abstract class, so you can't create instances of it directly, only instances of non-abstract derived classes.

As such, your `Add` class must use `Expression*` pointers (or `Expression&` references) rather than `Expression` objects, eg:

```
class Add : public Expression {
    private:
        Expression* left;
        Expression* right;
    public:
        Add(Expression* left, Expression* right)
            : left(left), right(right)
        {
        }

        Expression* evaluate() override {
            // use left->evaluate() and right->evaluate() as needed...
        }
};
```

Or:

```
class Add : public Expression {
    private:
        Expression& left;
        Expression& right;
    public:
        Add(Expression& left, Expression& right)
            : left(left), right(right)
        {
        }

        Expression* evaluate() override {
            // use left.evaluate() and right.evaluate() as needed...
        }
};
```

Comment: what does `: left(left), right(right)` do?

Comment: @JoshuaMorris Read about [member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) on cppreference. Also see [What does the colon after a constructor mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785612/)

Comment: If I want to return an* Integer: Expression from the evaluate method, how would I set the new Integer equal to the return value?

Comment: Since `Number` derives from `Expression`, a `Number*` pointer is implicitly convertible into an `Expression*` pointer. So `evaluate()` can return an `Expression*` pointer to a `Number` object. Just know that the caller won't know that `evaluate()` returned a pointer to a `Number` object, unless it casts the `Expression*` pointer back to a `Number*` pointer, ie with `dynamic_cast`

Comment: how would I return it to the ```Number``` object?

Comment: If you know for a fact that the return value is a `Number`, then you can use `static_cast`, eg: `Expression* result = someExpression->evaluate(); Number* num = static_cast<Number*>(result); /* use num as needed ... */` Otherwise use `dynamic_cast` instead, eg: `Expression* result = someExpression->evaluate(); Number* num = dynamic_cast<Number*>(result); if (num) { /* use num as needed ... */ } else { /* not a number, do something else ... */ }`

Comment: I just remembered, my professor told me to use dynamic cast. the only return types for ```add.evaluate``` are Integer and Float, which are Expressions. So, I will dynamically cast whichever is the correct return for that case.

Answer (score -1):

Since `Expression` is an abstract class, you cannot actually have an entity which really is an `Expression`, which is what your `class Add` declares.

You have to use either references or pointers to `Expression`s which is of course going to make it difficult to control lifecycles -- i.e., you'll have to be careful to avoid dangling references, AKA use-after-free.  But here is how it should look:

```
class Add : Expression{
    private:
        Expression & left;
        Expression & right;
    public:
        Add(Expression & left, Expression & right){
            this->left = left;
            this->right = right;
        }
};
```

You will likely find it worthwhile to build some intelligence (lifecycle management) into your class so it uses smart pointers and makes copies of the `Expression` parameters;  otherwise you're going to encounter lots of core-dumps.

Comment: Your example won't compile either. References are not assignable and you do not initialise them. Not the mention the whole range of problems with having references as members (e.g. it makes `Add` non-assignable).

Comment: I would not use reference members here, since they will easily dangle. `std::unique_ptr` is a safer default choice

Comment: Reference members can only be initialized in the constructor's [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor), eg: `Add(Expression & left, Expression & right) : left(left), right(right) {}`