# Unexpected result from LeetCode (Minimum Path Sum)

Tags: c++

I used an online compiler to test my code, and it runs correctly. However, when I submit my code to LeetCode, it always returns a random negative number, like -1218055056.

The problem description is as below,

> **Given a m x n grid filled with non-negative numbers, find a path from top left to bottom right which minimizes the sum of all numbers along its path.**
>
> **Note: You can only move either down or right at any point in time.**

And my code is as below,

```
class Solution {
public:
    int sub(vector<vector<int> >& grid, int** dp, int m, int n) {
        if(dp[m][n] == 0) {
            if(m==0 && n==0) {
                *(*(dp+m)+n) = grid.at(m).at(n);
            } else {
                if(m == 0) {
                    *(*(dp+m)+n) = sub(grid, dp, m, n-1);
                } else if(n == 0) {
                    *(*(dp+m)+n) = sub(grid, dp, m-1, n);
                } else {
                    int left = sub(grid, dp, m, n-1);
                    int up = sub(grid, dp, m-1, n);
                    
                    *(*(dp+m)+n) = left<up?grid.at(m).at(n)+left:grid.at(m).at(n)+up;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return *(*(dp+m)+n);
    }
    
    int minPathSum(vector<vector<int> > &grid) {
        int m = grid.size();
        int n = grid.at(0).size();
        int** dp = new int*[m];
        for(int i=0; i<m; i++) {
            dp[i] = new int[n];
        }
        
        return sub(grid, dp, m-1, n-1);
    }
};
```

Does anyone know why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you initialize the vector? Provide a [SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions), that we can see all the relevant code.

Comment: Your code has two `new` statements and no `delete`. All pointers to allocated memory in `minPathSum` are lost at return. This is a memory leak. (Though likely unrelated to your problem)

Comment: Which line prints the unexpected value?

Comment: Also based on the top answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628311/array-initialisation) you use `dp[...][...]` uninitialized and thus with indeterminate values.

Comment: if `dp[...][...]` is uninitialized, shouldn't all its elements be 0? @Nabla

Comment: @UnkDrew No read the links I posted, they say `indeterminate`.

Comment: I set the vector to be [[1]], and it should return 1, but some random negative number instead @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: Please the comment above @Code-Guru

Comment: @UnkDrew Replace `dp[i] = new int[n];` with `dp[i] = new int[n]();` and report your findings. I am not sure I am correct, but interested.

Comment: So if I initialize all its elements to 0, will it solve the problem? @Nabla is it what you want to do?

Comment: I'd guess your vectors need to be initialized (`resize()`) correctly for the correct grid dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestions from the comments:

```
for(int i=0; i<m; i++) {
    dp[i] = new int[n];
}

return sub(grid, dp, m-1, n-1);
```

Here `dp[i]` is **not** zero-initialized, the values of `dp[i]` are *indeterminate* as `dp` is passed to `sub`. In `sub` the values are read before they are assigned to, so the behaviour may be very unexpected, in particular `sub` will return a indeterminate value from `dp` without doing anything else, if `dp[m][n]` is not zero, because of this test:

```
 if(dp[m][n] == 0) {
```

You might have been just lucky that the code ran correctly with your compiler. To correctly zero-initialize the values at declaration, use this:

```
 dp[i] = new int[n]();
```

Answer (score 0):

Nabla is right, replacing `dp[i] = new int[n];` with `dp[i] = new int[n]();` does solve the problem.